# why $\|Sx\|=\sup_{\|y\| \le 1} |\langle Sx, y \rangle|,\;\forall x\in E?$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be complex Hilbert space.

> If $S\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, why
>   $$\|Sx\|=\sup_{\|y\| \le 1} |\langle Sx, y \rangle|,\;\forall x\in E?$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the [Cauchy-Schwartz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality): For $\|y\|\leq 1$ we have
$$
|\langle Sx, y \rangle| \leq \sqrt{|\langle Sx, Sx \rangle|}\sqrt{|\langle y, y \rangle|} = \|Sx\| \|y\| \leq \|Sx\|.
$$
On the other hand, if we choose $y=\frac{1}{\|Sx\|}Sx$, then clearly $\|y\|=1$ and
$$
|\langle Sx, y \rangle| = \frac{1}{\|Sx\|}|\langle Sx, Sx \rangle| = \frac{1}{\|Sx\|}\|Sx\|^2 = \|Sx\|.
$$